# Call c native function from C# project

Tags: c#, c, wpf, dll, encryption

I'm working on a C# project where i have to store in a file, some passwords. I want to encrypt those ones with sha1.
I have already the encrypt / decrypt sha1 prog in a C project.
I want to call the "password_sha1_build", which is the C function which encrypt password extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char * Password_SHA1_Build(char *Password)), from my C# project.

I built a dll from the file where there is the "Password_SHA1_Build" function and i tried, to call it from my C# project like this :

```
[DllImport("Pass.dll")]
public static extern string Password_SHA1_Build(string Password);

... 

string password = "iamlee";
string hashedpwd = "";
hashedpwd = Password_SHA1_Build(password);
```

And i get an error (in french) about Pinvoke doesn't matched with the signature... unbalanced.
I tought that the matter could come from the fact that i'm using string / char *, but if it's the case, i can i deal with that?..

Please ask for any more informations if needed
Thanks to all

---

Hi thanks to all for your answers.

I noticed that i was not clear enough in my subject.
There is a C-program used as "server" which will read a file named infos.cfg where are stored the encrypted password wrote in the C#-program.
The C-program was not developed by myself but it contains a function named "int Password_SHA1_Check(char *Password, char *Hash)" which is able to read a sha1 password built by the function "char * Password_SHA1_Build(char *Password)".

So at first i tried to store the passwords with sha1 in c# like this :

```
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 hash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoder = newS ystem.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] combined = encoder.GetBytes(password);
hash.ComputeHash(combined);
//rethash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.Hash);
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));
string delimitedHexHash = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
string hexHash = delimitedHexHash.Replace("-", "");
rethash = hexHash;
```

The passwords are stored like this in a file : "password:sha1:576295.49880ab837e9179dd68dfb142342f368e821de43" before the "." is the salt and after is the hash

But when the C-program exec his Password_SHA1_Check he tells me that the password i entered is not the same as the password stored.
I'm kinda weak in crypto and busy by other works so i just asked myself "why not use the "Password_SHA1_Build" function which already exists and works" so that's why i tried to call this function from my C# programm.
I hope this is clear, i'm sorry my english is quite bad.

To Reed Copsey : thanks i tried that and at least the Pinvoke exception disapeared but now i got a "AccessViolationException"..
So any more ideas will be welcomed thanks again!

Comment: why you are not using .net SHA1 implementation?

Comment: It could the issue with Data Marshaling. see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

Comment: Your "answer" was really an update to the question so I merged it. Please edit your question to add new information.

Answer (score 2):

This is potentially due to a mismatched calling convention.  PInvoke uses `StdCall` by default, but the VC compilers use `CDecl` by default.

Try changing to:

```
[DllImport("Pass.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Other potential issues are the string marshaling technique.  You may need to specify the encoding to use, and/or pass as `StringBuilder` as a second parameter and use it to "fill in" the results.

Answer (score 0):

.Net framework has a lots of encrypted algorithms built-in, including SHA256. Try using [SHA256Managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256managed.aspx) class. And if you want to decrypt your password eventuatlly, you need symmetric encryption function, and SHA is not one of them.

Take a look at this post: [Password retrieval and storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640051/password-retrieval-and-storage/15640080#15640080)